# SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

An employee mapped with 2 supervisors for specific periods. I need to find the supervisor which the employee mapped maximum period.

Employee Mapped with the supervisor A from '01/01/2010' to '31/08/2010'
Mapped with the supervisor B from '01/09/2010' to '31/12/2010'

So the maximum period of the supervisor is 'A'

This should find using sql server query.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Can you post some DDL so we can create some sample data? At the very least maybe you could give us a general idea of your tables and data.

Comment: Can you post the table structures

Comment: @Girija: your Bio states you are a SQL Developer; shouldn't this be your job to write some TSQL?

Comment: @Mitch and @lanC this might be a minor point but @girija stated he was a SOFTWARE pro WORKING AS as SQL developer which means to me someone just tossed the SQL hat to him today.

Comment: @ RC_Cleland : OK, good point. I still think people should make an attempt and THEN post here. (Also, I'm not 100% sure that his Bio wasn't edited since I pointed it out! ;) )

Answer (score 1):

As no DDL has been posted as yet, this may or may not help.

```
Select  e.EmployeeName,
        s.SupervisorName,
        es.StartDate,
        es.EndDate,
        EmpMaxDays.MaxDays as 'TotalNumberOfDaysAssigned'

From dbo.Employees e

Left Join dbo.EmployeeSupervisors es on es.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeId

Left Join
(
Select Max(DateDiff(day, es.StartDate, es.EndDate)) as 'MaxDays',
        EmployeeId
From dbo.EmployeeSupervisor
Group By EmployeeId
)EmpMaxDays on es.EmployeeId = EmpMaxDays.EmployeeId

Left Join dbo.Supervisros s on es.SupervisorId = s.SupervisorId

Where DateDiff(day, es.StartDate, es.EndDate) = EmpMaxDays.MaxDays
And es.EmployeeId = EmpMaxDays.EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use rank partitioning. This way you can select where the rank = 1 (the correct match). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).